# Rails 3.2 - PgTools set_search_path not working from helper method

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, multi-tenant

## UPDATE 8/8/2012

I have narrowed down the problem somewhat...

This line works

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path = ["11", "public"].join(",")
```

but this line doesn't

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path = [workspace.id.to_s, "public"].join(",")
```

even when workspace.id == 11

To be clear, "workspace.id" does not get updated for each iteration of the loop.  Note that this only applies to the ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path command

Any ideas?

## ORIGINAL POST

Apologies for the long-winded post, but I'm really stuck.

## BACKGROUND

I am developing a multi-tenant app on Rails, using PostGreSQL.  Tenants are seperated via PG schemas.  I have the concept of a "workspace" which is owned by a tenant, and has an associated record in the "public" schema.

Each individual schema (workspace) has a "Projects" table.

On every page, I would like to display a dropdown list of workspaces and projects to which the current user has access.  A simplified version of the dropdown would look like this:

```
Workspace 1
- Project 1a
- Project 1b
Workspace 2
- Project 2a
- Project 2b
- Project 2c
...
...
Workspace 8
Project 8a
```

I have the following methods in lib/PgTools.rb

```
def self.current_search_path
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value "SHOW search_path"
end

def self.set_search_path(name, include_public = true)
  path_parts = [name.to_s, ("public" if include_public)].compact
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path = path_parts.join(",")
end
```

These methods appear to work fine when used from the rails console.

## ISSUE

I have written a helper method in application_helper.rb to create the dropdown.  I figured this was a good place to put it since it has to be displayed on every page.  Within this helper method, I have to set the PG search path (using PgTools.set_search_path) so that only projects from the appropriate workspace are iterated over.  BUT the search path does not seem to get set correctly.

Relevant code is below

```
current_user.workspaces.each do |workspace|


  html << '<li>' + workspace.name + "</li>"

  PgTools.set_search_path(workspace.id) unless Rails.env.test?
  html << '<li>Current search_path is ' + PgTools.current_search_path + '</li>'  <!-- DEBUG LINE
  Project.all.each do |project|

    html << "<li>"

    html << (link_to '- ' + project.name, edit_project_path(project.id))

    html << "</li>"
  end
end
```

When I view the output, I get the following:

```
Workspace 1
  Setting search_path to 10
  Current search_path is 10, public
  - Project 1a
Workspace 2
  Setting search_path to 15
  Current search_path is 10, public
  - Project 1a
Workspace 3
  Setting search_path to 14
  Current search_path is 10, public
  - Project 1a
```

As you can see, the search path never gets changed, and I have no idea why.  The module methods are obviously accessible since the "current_search_path" method works fine.

When I tail log/development.log, I get the following output:

```
Workspace Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "workspaces".* FROM "workspaces" INNER JOIN "workspace_memberships" ON "workspaces"."id" = wworkspace_memberships"."workspace_id" WHERE "workspace_memberships"."user_id" = 2 ORDER BY workspaces.name ASC
(0.1ms)  SHOW search_path
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
CACHE (0.0ms)  SHOW search_path
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
CACHE (0.0ms)  SHOW search_path
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
CACHE (0.0ms)  SHOW search_path
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
CACHE (0.0ms)  SHOW search_path
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
CACHE (0.0ms)  SHOW search_path
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
CACHE (0.0ms)  SHOW search_path
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
CACHE (0.0ms)  SHOW search_path
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
CACHE (0.0ms)  SHOW search_path
```

which might suggest a caching issue, but I'm really flying blind here, and didn't like the thought of disabling caching because I have no idea what other impacts that might have.

Any idea most welcome.  I am also open to suggestions that I am going totally the wrong way to achieve the end result.

Cheers,

Kyle.

Comment: Instead of disabling caching, maybe just flush the cache (not that I know what the incantation for that is)? Also, what about the connection pool? instead of executing the SQL directly on a single connection, it seems more like you need to somehow execute the statement on all open connections, plus force the statement to be executed for new connections that might happen to get opened.

Comment: @steve Thanks for the answer, but I am looking to solve this issue in the context of a Rails application.  I'm not sure if what you suggest is possible/feasible???

Comment: Perhaps this Rails pull request 7083 might be of help: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7083

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting. Here's the source:

```
  def schema_search_path=(schema_csv)
    if schema_csv
      execute("SET search_path TO #{schema_csv}", 'SCHEMA')
      @schema_search_path = schema_csv
    end
  end
```

Not that it would matter considering those two statement should evaluate to the exact same thing. Have you tried putting parentheses around the id.to_s?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your schema names start with a number. I had a similar problem where I was using hashes as schema names. Here's the solution:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path = %{"#{workspace.id}", public}
```

The `%{}` is just another way of defining a string so that you can use the actual quote marks in your string itself.

I hope that helps :D